# Ionic Crosswalk "Cannot load external extensions due to old version of runtime library"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk

I've been working on an Ionic app and have successfully built it on iOS and am trying to build it into android, previous versions have built fine but now when I try and run a release version of my app I get the "Unfortunately, [My app name] has stopped." message after about a half a second of loading screen. My environment info is:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.15
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.2
Crosswalk Version: 18+
Android SDK version: 23
```

When I run adb logcat I get this message before it crashes:

```
E/XWalkExternalExtensionManagerImpl(18395): Cannot load external extensions due to old version of runtime library
D/XWalkLib(18395): Init reserved object: class org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaResourceClient
D/XWalkLib(18395): Call reserved method: public void org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewBridge.setResourceClientSuper(org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkResourceClientBridge)
D/XWalkLib(18395): Init reserved object: class org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaUiClient
D/XWalkLib(18395): Call reserved method: public void org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewBridge.setUIClientSuper(org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkUIClientBridge)
D/XWalkLib(18395): Call reserved method: class org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewBridge.setXWalkViewInternalVisibilitySuper
W/dalvikvm(18395): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41836438)
E/AndroidRuntime(18395): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18395): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewBridge.setXWalkViewInternalVisibilitySuper
E/AndroidRuntime(18395):    at org.xwalk.core.ReflectMethod.invoke(ReflectMethod.java:57)
E/AndroidRuntime(18395):    at org.xwalk.core.XWalkCoreWrapper.handlePostInit(XWalkCoreWrapper.java:169)
E/AndroidRuntime(18395):    at org.xwalk.core.XWalkLibraryLoader$ActivateTask.onPostExecute(XWalkLibraryLoader.java:306)
E/AndroidRuntime(18395):    at org.xwalk.core.XWalkLibraryLoader$ActivateTask.onPostExecute(XWalkLibraryLoader.java:277)
E/AndroidRuntime(18395):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
E/AndroidRuntime(18395):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
E/AndroidRuntime(18395):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
E/AndroidRuntime(18395):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(18395):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(18395):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4905)
E/AndroidRuntime(18395):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18395):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(18395):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
E/AndroidRuntime(18395):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
E/AndroidRuntime(18395):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've tried various versions of the crosswalk plugin, removed and re-added the android platform and removed code/plugins that were different between this version and the last and this error keeps coming up.

This is my crosswalk info in config.xml

```
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="xwalk_core_library_beta:18+" />
<preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
<preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded" />
<preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="true" />
```

I've tried looking up the uncaught exception error and the cannot load external extensions due to an old runtime library and haven't found any answers. Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** I think there might be some issue with crosswalk not properly referencing external libraries I found this in the adb log just above the error I posted above :

```
D/XWalkLib(19248): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load xwalkcore: findLibrary returned null
D/XWalkLib(19248): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: load_library[1093]: Library '/data/data/<my-app-id>/app_xwalkcore/libxwalkcore.so' not found
```

And when I build the app there is this 'null' printout just below JAVA_HOME:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<ME>/Documents/android-sdk-macosx
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
null
org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:18+
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
```

My other apps usually have a printout of stuff here, I believe this might be the cause. I still haven't found the solution and am still looking.

**Edit2:** An update on the situation if anyone else has run into this. The problem never really got solved per say but rather I just ended up ignoring it. Throughout my entire time of building apps I've always tested the x86 build on my android device (LG Optimus E973) and its always ran and worked, I never tried the Arm7 because at the time I assumed a device could only run one or the other. It turns out for some reason I'm unsure whether or not it was a code change I did or something that changed in the crosswalk library but the x86 build does not work on my android device anymore and will crash immediately. I tried out the Arm7 and it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Do you happen to use a Galaxy Tab3 10.1? A few of our users have reported the exact same issue, and all of them have that exact device (out of hundreds of Android-users).

Version: xwalk_core_library:18+.
I'm currently finding out if a fallback to our previous Crosswalk version (15) solves the problem for these users. I'll let you know!

Comment: I was actually testing on an LG Optimus E973, and I discovered that it was only the x86 version of the app that experienced the issue I was having. I posted an update on what happened above. The issue I was having I believe still exists though because for some unexplained reason the x86 version stopped building correctly. Thanks for your inquiry though I'd be curious to know if the problem i'm having on this device is the same as those other users you mentioned and if it is fixed by reverting to v15

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to build a ionic app based on Crosswalk plugin. But I couldn't reproduce the problem your are facing. Here's my procedures

```
ionic start myApp tabs
cd myApp
ionic platform add android
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
ionic build android
ionic emulate android
```

However, I noticed that you were building with the beta version of crosswalk.

```
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="xwalk_core_library_beta:18+" />
```

Could you change it to the stable channel and try again?

```
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="xwalk_core_library:18+" />
```

Comment: did try running the v18 stable version as well as version 14 and 17 however I couldn't get the app to even build on those 2 versions. I posted an edit above about the current situation. Thanks for your help though.